# What is the compopt equivalent in zsh that modifies the current completion options?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, zsh

I am writing an auto completion script for zsh that I want to enable nospace on certain conditions. The bash equivalent script would look like this

```
_my_completion(){
  if something; then
    compopt -o nospace
  fi
}

complete -F _my_completion <exec>
```

How do I achieve the same goal in zsh?

Answer (score 2):

The similar effect can be done using `-S ''` as `compadd` argument, as you can see:

```sh
_my_completion(){
  # Here you can access ${words[@]}, $BUFFER, $CURSOR, $NAME, $CURRENT...
  if something; then
    completions_array=(foo bar baz)

    # `-S ''` is the equivalent of `compopt -o nospace`
    compadd -S '' -a completions_array
  fi
}

compdef _my_completion <exec>
```

If you're familiar with bash completions, you can see how zsh completions compare in [this script that loads the bash completions in ZSH](https://github.com/3v1n0/zsh-bash-completions-fallback/blob/master/zsh-bash-completions-fallback.plugin.zsh).